# How to show the content for selected Radio button using AngularJs and make the json data editable?

Tags: angularjs, json, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to make the some Json data editable using AngularJs which contains list of radio types options. Currently the "Qty" field is displaying with both options. I want to show the "Qty" field for only if "Shared Items" option is selected from radio list in both "read-only" and "editable" mode. So how to get this? Here is the Plunker link: https://embed.plnkr.co/Zmz8N0/
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you were missing is how radio buttons work.

You were using the radio buttons in ng-repeat and assigned to them different ng-model! They need to have same ng-model but different ng-values.

You were using different ng-model for them so you actually cannot grap the radio button's value.

The change i made in your HTML is that i put the radio buttons outside your ng-repeat and gave them same ng-model and differenet ng-values, then we used the radio button's value with your ng-if condition on the "Qty" field.

https://embed.plnkr.co/Gn2wi1FVyS8fLi7m6iU0/

Best of luck,

Comment: Thanks. But if there are multiple radio options (i.e. item types) from json array then how it would be?

Comment: You can achieve that by assigning same ng model but different ng values then use the ng model to extract the value..